# typescript type throw error when use lodash set with redux tookit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

typescript CRA template with @reduxjs/tookit.
lodash/set is an easy way to update nested state in @reduxjs/toolkit, here is my code.

```js
import set from 'lodash/set'
import { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

state = {
  a: 'a',
  b: [1,2,3]
  c: {
    d: [
      {e: 5}
    ]
  }
  // ...
}

// reducer
setStateWithPathList: (state, action:PayloadAction<{ [key: string]: any }>) => {
  Object.keys(action).forEach(key => {
    const val = action[key]
    set(state, key, val)
  }) 
}

// when run this in Component
// throw Error:
// Argument of type '{ a: string; b: never[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type'[string, unknown]'.
dispatch(setStateWithPathList({
  a: '',
  b: [],
}))
```

Comment: You need to use and `Object.keys(action.payload)` and `const val = action.payload[key]`.

Comment: Why not just `Object.assign(state, action.payload)` instead of all that magic?